# Server is Distributor, but Can't set database for replication

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

I Have a server that is already a Distributor. This happened in the past. Nobody nowadays knows why it is configured as a distributor, there's not even the "distributor" database.

[image]

We don't know if something is using it, or why it was created.

Since I saw already that it's a distributor, I tried to add a database for replication, and got this error:

`exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'>>DATABASE<<', @optname = N'publish', @value = N'true'`

```
Msg 20028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure >>DATABASE<<.sys.sp_MSpublishdb, Line 56 [Batch Start Line 3]
The Distributor has not been installed correctly. Could not enable database for publishing.
The replication option 'publish' of database 'DATABASE' has been set to false.
```

So I would like to know, **how can I track who's using it, what's using it, is it safe to remove and configure it again**?

because, when I tried to set a replication for the database, I got this error ( Right click on replication folder >> follow wizard ):

And since it's a distributor already, why can't I use it to enable replication on that database?

[image]

We are pretty confident that nothing is using this. but I don't touch anything without 100% of certain.

Comment: My opinion is that nothing *can* be using it because it's not installed properly anyway. But don't take a random guy on the internet's opinion if you need 100% confidence.

Comment: yeah I actually removed and fixed, no complains at all, will let the question here since maybe there will be someone knowing a good way to monitor it.